# I want to recommend 2 products: should I leave one or two answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

(This question is basic but I couldn't find the answer skimming through meta.)

I read a question, and I want to recommend 2 products that seem to match the requirements: should I leave one or two answers?

In the software recommendation Stack Exchange website, typically 1 answer contains 1 program only, so that users can vote and comment directly on a program (e.g., if the answer contains 1 good program and 1 crapware, casting a vote would be meaningless).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each recommendation should be its own answer. This allows users to vote on the merits of each one without confusing what they are voting for. Each answer should be complete and contain details to answer the question, not just a link referring to the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this solution (but like I was asked I divided [my answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2596/1366) to two separate answers). There is many answers which recommend not one but many products in different price ranges (best in price) or in different technologies (for bigger comparission, so User which asked question can take his own decision or can have bigger knowledge about range of products he can choose). Personally I often add conclusion at the end and product which I would choose but the decision I leave to the User which asked question.

Example answers:

- [Flat keyboard](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2590/1366) - many technologies
- [Cheap mobile server](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2387/1366) - old and new product
- [Android phone under $180](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2277/1366) - two prices (best in price range)
- [Motherboard for a new college desktop computer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/241/1366) - two technologies

I think all this answers are valuable but with this rule they should be split to 2-3 answers where they can loose their value or they will be similar with many repetitions. I think that if at the end of the answer there will be conclusion and direct recommendation for one of the products answer should be accepted.

Comment: I don't think splitting the answers makes them lose their value. It focuses the answers to a single product. There may be two very similar products (like your answers [here](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2600/57)), but each has their own advantages/disadvantage. With individual answers, you can focus on those pros and cons per product. If this ends up creating duplicates, we have multiple options to deal with those: Community Wikis, Simple upvotes, competing answers with the same product, or elimination of the duplicate answer.